# Cannot understand how will Entity Framewrok generate a SQL statement for an Update operation using timestamp?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following method inside my asp.net mvc web application :

```
var rack = IT.ITRacks.Where(a => !a.Technology.IsDeleted && a.Technology.IsCompleted);

foreach (var r in rack)
{
                long? it360id = technology[r.ITRackID];

                if (it360resource.ContainsKey(it360id.Value))
                {
                    long? CurrentIT360siteid = it360resource[it360id.Value];

                    if (CurrentIT360siteid != r.IT360SiteID)
                    {
                        r.IT360SiteID = CurrentIT360siteid.Value;
                        IT.Entry(r).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }

                IT.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I checked SQL Server profiler I noted that EF will generated the following SQL statement:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[ITSwitches]
set [ModelID] = @0, [Spec] = null, [RackID] = @1, [ConsoleServerID] = null, [Description] = null, [IT360SiteID] = @2, [ConsoleServerPort] = null
where (([SwitchID] = @3) and ([timestamp] = @4))
select [timestamp]
from [dbo].[ITSwitches]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [SwitchID] = @3',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 bigint,@3 int,@4 binary(8)',@0=1,@1=539,@2=1502,@3=1484,@4=0x00000000000EDCB2
```

I can not understand the purpose of having the following section :-

```
select [timestamp]
    from [dbo].[ITSwitches]
    where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [SwitchID] = @3',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 bigint,@3 int,@4 binary(8)',@0=1,@1=539,@2=1502,@3=1484,@4=0x00000000000EDCB2
```

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Does your table have a column of `timestamp` data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because EF (and you) want to update the updated client-side object by the newly generated rowversion value.

First the update is executed. If this succeeds (because the rowversion is still the one you had in the client) a new rowversion is generated by the database and EF retrieves that value. Suppose you'd immediately want to make a second update. That would be impossible if you didn't have the new rowversion.

This happens with all properties that are marked as identity or computed (by `DatabaseGenertedOption`).

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework uses timestamps to check whether a row has changed.  If the row has changed since the last time EF retrieved it, then it knows it has a concurrency problem.

Here's an explanation:

http://www.remondo.net/entity-framework-concurrency-checking-with-timestamp/

Comment: yes i know that , and i know that EF will include the timestamp in thw where clause . but my question was that it already add the timestamp to the Where clause ""where (([SwitchID] = @3) and ([timestamp] = @4))"" so what is the reason to include ""select [timestamp]
from [dbo].[ITSwitches]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0....""